# Why is faces being added to my url?

Tags: jsf

I have the following in my web.xml (please note, there are no servlet-mappings):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>CourseManagementJDBC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and when I right-click on the addCourse.jsp file in my project (as instructed in my book) the following url is launced in eclipse:

```
http://localhost:8090/CourseManagementJDBC/faces/addCourse.jsp
```

I have restarted eclipse, restarted Tomcat, cleaned the project, done a clean install, and none of it is removing that faces from the url.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had already seen that link and I still cannot seen anything in it that explains why I am getting faces added to my URL. It may be there, but I cannot see it.

Comment: Probably you accidentally created a JSF page instead of a JSP page and made Eclipse confused about your intents.